# Create a specific amount of function duplicates and run them simultaneously

Tags: python, multithreading, algorithm, concurrency, python-asyncio

I have an async program based around a set of multiple infinitely-running functions that run simultaneously.

I want to allow users to run a specific amount of specific function duplicates.

A code example of what I have now:

```py
async def run():
  await asyncio.gather(
    func_1(arg1, arg2),
    func_2(arg2),
    func_3(arg1, arg3),
  )
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(run())
loop.close()
```

Let's say a user wants to run 2 instances of `func_2`. I want the core code to look like this:

```py
async def run():
  await asyncio.gather(
    func_1(arg1, arg2),
    func_2(arg2),
    func_2(arg2),
    func_3(arg1, arg3),
  )
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(run())
loop.close()
```

Any way to elegantly achieve this?

Comment: keep in mind that since Python 3.7, instead of `loop = asyncio.get_event_loop(); loop.run_until_complete(run()); loop.close()` you can (and should) simply do `asyncio.run(run())` (asyncio.run being the new call in asyncio, and the inner `run()`  being your function)

Answer (score 0):

Just pass asyncio functions to where you do `asyncio.gather`;

```py
from typing import List, Coroutine
import asyncio

async def func1(arg1, arg2):
    print(arg1, arg2)

async def func2(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    print(arg1, arg2, arg3)

async def run(functions: List[Coroutine]):
    await asyncio.gather(*functions)

functions = [func1(1, 2), func2(3, 4, 5)]
asyncio.run(run(functions))
```

Different from sync code, calling an async function without an `await` returns a `coroutine` object, not the result of the function, which means you can just pass the function with arguments to another function without issues.

For your use-case, the user can just pass `func1` and `func2` in a list with their preset params to be ran, as many times as they want.